# Find the most reliable path - Dijkstra’s algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, computer-science, dijkstra

We are given a directed graph G = (V, E) on which each edge (u, v) ∈ E has an associated
value r(u, v), which is a real number in the range 0 ≤ r(u, v) ≤ 1 that represents the reliability of a communication channel from vertex u to vertex v. We interpret r(u, v) as the
probability that the channel from u to will not fail, and we assume that these probabilities
are independent. Give an efficient algorithm to find the most reliable path between two given
vertices.

```
     a
    / \
   b<--c         a directed to c; c directed to b; b directed to a
```

Let's say this is graph G = (V, E); vertex a is the root, one of the edge is a to c. a = u & c = v so edge is (u, v). I want to use Dijkstra’s algorithm to solve this, but not sure how.

```
     a
      \
   b<--c          path c: a -> c   &    b: a -> c -> b
```

Can someone explain the most reliable path in the simplest way possible?

This question is from Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition, chp 24.3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's not about a practical programming problem.

Answer (score 3):

> We interpret r(u, v) as the probability that the channel from u to
> will not fail, and we assume that these probabilities are independent.

From this you can deduce that the probability that a given path will not fail is equal to the product of the `r(u,v)` of all edges `(u,v)` that make up the path.

You want to maximize that product.

This is exactly like the shortest path problem, for which you surely know an algorithm, except instead of minimizing a sum, you are trying to maximize a product.

There is a cool tool to go from products to sums: it's the logarithm. Logarithm is an increasing function, thus maximizing a product is the same as maximizing the logarithm of that product. But logarithm has the additional cool property that the logarithm of a product is equal to the sum of the logarithms:

```
log(a * b * c * d * ...) = log(a) + log(b) + log(c) + log(d) + ...
```

Thus maximizing the product of the reliabilities `r(u,v)` is the same as maximizing the sum of the log-reliabilities `log(r(u,v))`.

Since the reliabilities are probabilities of the edges, they are values between 0 (excluded) and 1 (included). You can exclude 0 because if an edge had a reliability of 0, you can remove that edge from the graph. Since `0 < r(u,v) <= 1`, it follows that `log(r(u,v))` is negative or 0.

So you are trying to maximize a sum of negative values. This is exactly the same as minimizing the sum of the opposite values.

Thus: apply your shortest-path algorithm, using `-log(r(u,v))` as the lengths of the edges.

Comment: what would be the run time of this algorithm? O(log V) ?

Comment: @Sam Isn't that explained in your book? Hint: O(log V) is extraordinarily optimistic, as it would imply the algorithm doesn't have time to look at more than a very small number of nodes.